# Checking if name already exists and also type of name in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am checking for if name exist in the stored procedure. So basically checking if `attr_name` exists in the `ibui_attribute` table.

Here the `attr_name` can be either of the two types. There is column in the table called `is_group` that tells you if the attribute is a group or an attribute. I need to throw the error accordingly and hence written and if else condition. Do  I need to write a query again to check if the attribute is group or an attribute for the if else condition or can I do that in the if exist SQL statement that has been written

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [IBT].[save_ibui_attribute]
  @p_attr_id           INT          = NULL,
  @p_is_group          BIT          = 0,
  @p_attr_name         VARCHAR (20),
  @p_attr_desc         VARCHAR (250),
  @p_parent_attr_id    INT,
  @p_attr_level        VARCHAR (20),
  @p_attr_data_type    VARCHAR (8),
  @p_last_updt_user_nm VARCHAR (30) = NULL,
  @p_last_updt_dtime   DATETIME     = NULL,
  @debug AS            BIT          = 0
AS
BEGIN
  BEGIN TRY
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE
      @logfile VARCHAR (MAX),
      @msg     VARCHAR (255);

    SET @msg = 'IBT.save_ibui_attribute Starts';

    IF @debug = 1
    BEGIN
        SELECT 'IBT.save_ibui_attribute DEBUG START';
    END;

    IF @p_attr_id IS NULL
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS (SELECT attr_name
                   FROM IBT.ibt_attribute
                   WHERE UPPER(attr_name) = UPPER(@p_attr_name))
        BEGIN
            IF ATTRIBUTE
                RAISERROR ( 50001, 16, 1, 'ERROR! : New attribute has a name that is already in use. Please use a different attribute name' );
            ELSE 
                IF GROUP
                   RAISERROR (50001, 16, 1, 'ERROR! : New group has a name that is already in use. Please use a different group name' );
        END;
    END;
END;
```

Do I do something like this

```
declare @isGroup  bit;
    IF @p_attr_id IS NULL
    BEGIN
      
     SET  @isGroup = (SELECT is_group
                      FROM IBT.ibt_attribute
                      WHERE UPPER(attr_name) = UPPER(@p_attr_name))

      IF  @isGroup = 0
        RAISERROR ( 50001, 16, 1, 'ERROR! : New attribute has a name that is aleady in use. Please use a different attribute name' );
        ELSE IF @isGroup = 1
         RAISERROR ( 50001, 16, 1, 'ERROR! : New group has a name that is aleady in use. Please use a different group name' );
      END;
    END;
```

Comment: Just in case you aren't aware, but both SQL Server 2008 and 2012 are *completely* unsupported now; you should really be looking at upgrade paths, if you aren't already/

Comment: Is your `IBT.ibt_attribute` table an EAV anti-pattern table? If so, have you considered _fixing_ your database-design?

Comment: I feel like we're missing context here; Why do you need to check if the value is in the table? Are you planning to the `INSERT` or `UPDATE` that value into a table? If so, why aren't you using a `UNIQUE` `CONSTRAINT`?

Comment: this is an existing storedproc and does not have unique contraint check on it unfortunately. There is limitation for me to get that changed and using the existing approach which is being used for a while. At the moment the storeproc which is live is returning a common error message if it is attribute or a group. There is necessity to throw specific error message based on its type. Yes based on if it exist or not, we are inserting or updating the record. The question now is how to throw specific error

Comment: I think the fact that isgroup contains a value which means it exists hence if exist query may not be required